# Show hexadecimal color in angularjs ui-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-select

I have a ui-select, in which one of its attributes called color is in hexadecimal, is it possible with angular js to show that color?

```
<div class="form-group container-fluid">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Categoría:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <ui-select ng-model="activity.category" theme="bootstrap"  title="Selecciona una categoría">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Selecciona una categoría">
          {{ $select.selected.name }}
        </ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="category in categories | filter: $select.search">
          {{ category.name + category.color}}
        </ui-select-choices>
      </ui-select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? *not tested*

`<ui-select-choices repeat="category in categories | filter: $select.search>
    {{ category.name }} <button style="background-color:{{category.color}}"></button>
</ui-select-choices>`

Of course, you could use any `<div>`, but button is easy for this example.

Comment: Exactly as it is !!, but I have an error in this part background-color: {{category.color}}, a term expected

Comment: your answer helped me find a solution, thank you very much !!, ng-style="{'background-color': '{{category.color}}'}"

Comment: No problem :). Was that error just in your editor, or in the browser? It may be that the editor didn’t understand that mixture but angular compiled it fine.